# Hide property of Class3 instance in Class1 and show Class2

Tags: c#, class, properties

i got `Class1` and `Class2`, they both have instance of `Class3` which has property `MyName`... is it possible to hide property `MyName` of `Class3` instance in `Class1` and show only in `Class2`?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to remove `MyName` from `Class3`, then create a `Class4` which derives from `Class3` and has the property `MyName`. Create an instance of `Class4` where you want to "show" this property and an instance of `Class3` where you want to "hide" it.

Answer (score 0):

Create two classes that implement same interface.

```
public class Class3 : IClass
{

}

public class Class4 : IClass
{
    public string MyName{get;set;} 
}

public class Class1
{
    IClass _IClass;

    public Class1(IClass class)
    {
        this._IClass = class;
    }   
}

public class Class2
{
    IClass _IClass;

    public Class2(IClass class)
    {
        this._IClass = class;
    }   
}
```

When you create instance of Class1, Class2 inject relevent implementation.

```
Class1 class1 = new Class1(new Class3());
Class2 class2 = new Class2(new Class4());
```

Comment: Is there any difference in using interface inheritance or just class?